# LUIS no funciona cuando integro el webchat de bot framework v4 con javascript en ningún navegador

Tags: javascript

Creé un chatbot en c# con .net core con la platilla de [my virtual Assistant](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/tutorials/csharp/virtualassistant.md) y funciona bien en la liga de https://webchat.botframework.com... y también cuando lo intergo a un sitio con el iframe que nos da el canal de webchat

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/NAME_OF_BOT?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'  style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'></iframe>
```

pero LUIS no funciona cuando integro el chatbot con js en ningún navegador

```
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
<script>
 window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
       directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
          secret: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_SECRET'
       }),

    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
 );</script>
```

Qué puedo hacer para que funciona?
Ya intenté poniendo el secret del webchat y de directline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appication Insights me enviaba este error: The given key 'es' was not present in the dictionary.

Cambié el código a esto:

```
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
<script>
 window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
    {
       directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({
          secret: 'YOUR_DIRECT_LINE_SECRET'
       }),
locale: 'en-US',
    },
    document.getElementById('webchat')
 );</script>
```

Para cambiar el idioma de español a inglés y ya no me mandó ningún error.